# Mounting Volumes not Working OSX 10.10 + Boot2Docker 1.5

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, osx-mavericks, boot2docker

I'm trying to attach a volume to a docker container when it starts as a way of providing input to the docker container. When I type:

```
docker run swanijam/djredcap-harvest -v Users/swanickj/testFolder/Dock/Input:/Input
```

The Input folder never appears in the container.

I'm aware that there have been issues of boot2docker not having access to /Users but in my VirtualBox /Users is shared, as is default in boot2docker > 1.3.

The Input folder is being accessed in the ENTRYPOINT line of my Dockerfile, when it is built.

If you need me to show you any code or other files, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention to the path you are using. It should be:

```
docker run swanijam/djredcap-harvest -v /Users/swanickj/testFolder/Dock/Input:/Input
```

Boot2docker automatically mounts the /Users folders from your mac, and you should find it inside your boot2docker instance as:

```
cd /Users
```

Hope it helps you.